# How to distinguish between 为 and 给 when both means "for"

Tags: difference, word

Both 给 and 为 can mean "for." Both can be used with verbs to express an action done **for** anyone.

**So how can I distinguish?** Please make it clear.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

My feeling is:

That 给 is for doing something ''for'' someone.

I will buy it for you. 我给你买。

You will do the verb for someone else.

And 为 is more abstract

I am sad for you. 我为你伤心。

I'm not native but I don't think you could say:

我为你买东西。  X

我给你伤心。   X

Answer (score 1):

If you do something 'for someone's sake' or 'on behalf of someone', you can use 给

> [给 + noun] = [for + noun (for noun's sake)] e.g. 给我买东西 (buy thing for me = buy thing for my sake)
>
> [给 + noun] = [for + noun (on behalf of noun)] e.g. 给我重重打 (severely beat someone for me = beat someone on my behalf). In this case, 给 is interchangeable with 替 (on behalf of)

If you do something 'for someone's sake', or 'because of someone' you can use 为

> [为 + noun] = [for + noun (for noun's sake)] e.g. 为我买东西 (buy thing for me = buy thing for my sake)
>
> [为 + noun] = [because + noun ] e.g. 为我而受苦 (suffering because of me). In this case, 为 is interchangeable with 因 (because of)

Comment: In your first meaning of 给 and 为 that is "for someone's sake", what is the difference between them? E.g: 
(1) 他为我买东西.
(2) 他给我买东西.
I mean what is the difference between two sentences in terms of characteristics of action?

Comment: Both  "他为我买东西"  and  "他给我买东西 "can  mean  "he buy thing for me" (for my sake)  The difference between  the two is '给' is more specific -- --  The thing is bought  for me to own, or use; while 为 is more general (他为我买东西), can also mean (he bought thing for my sake, but not necessary for me to own or use, For example:   他为我买人寿保险 could mean "I am the insured" or "he is the insured". If it was "他给我买人寿保险" then I would be the insured for sure